# match pattern in line 1 and if yes print line 2

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following contents:

```
# 23 hits found
A_246   sme-miR-752-3p  100.00  12  0   0   1   12  6   17  0.14    23.3
--
# 16 hits found
A_699   bmo-miR-3326    100.00  10  0   0   4   13  6   15  1.9     19.6
```

If the first line has `# 23 hits found`  I need to print first column of the second line only with a tab.

For example in this file I would get :

```
# 23 hits found A_246
```

I tried the following command however I could not quite understand how to get the second line first column printed:

```
awk '/# 23 hits found/' microns_seq1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file (awk0) with the awk code.

```
/# 23 hits found/ { got_cnt = $0
                    next}
got_cnt != ""     { print got_cnt $1
                    got_cnt = ""}`
```

Then run:
`awk -f awk0 microns_seq1`

Good luck!

Comment: The `BEGIN` block is redundant here.

Comment: @sudo_O Yes. You are right. I have edited the answer to reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This awk should work:

```
awk '/^# [0-9]+ hits found$/{l=$0; getline; print l "\t" $1}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing some interpolation and not taking your question literally, I think you could want:

```
$ awk 'f{print $1;f=0}/# [0-9]+ hits found/{printf "%s\t",$0;f=1}' file
# 23 hits found     A_246
# 16 hits found     A_699
```